# Sequelize: Converting String column value to Date before using it in where clause

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

The issue I am facing is that I cannot get the column converted from string to date in order to actively use it within the where clause in Sequelize.

An example SQL which works

```
select * from sold_prices_england where  STR_TO_DATE(lodgement_date, '%d/%m/%Y') > STR_TO_DATE(DYNAMIC_VALUE_HERE,'%d/%m/%Y')
```

The code code to convert the column is `Sequelize.fn('STR_TO_DATE', Sequelize.col('lodgement_date'), '%d/%m/%Y');` but what I am trying to do is to convert the value from the column before using it within the where clause.

This is what I am trying to achieve

```
.
. // other clauses above and below
.
 lodgement_date: { // but where lodgement_date is a date and not a string
      [Op.gt]:
        Sequelize.fn('STR_TO_DATE', moment(start_date).format('DD/MM/YYYY'), '%d/%m/%Y'),
    },
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Sequelize.where` and `Sequelize.fn` to achieve your condition like this:

```js
Sequelize.where(
 Sequelize.fn('STR_TO_DATE', Sequelize.col('lodgement_date'), '%d/%m/%Y'),
 Op.gt,
 Sequelize.fn('STR_TO_DATE', moment(start_date).format('DD/MM/YYYY'), '%d/%m/%Y')
)
```